# Can not access checkbox by array in table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I made 3 input checkbox with input name, id, dt, ts. where dt and ts are disabled so when i click id then input dt and ts will be enabled, but i have problem can not access array.

```
<table id="tbl_employee" class="table table-striped table-bordered show-child-rows"  style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center" width="5%">ID</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="5%">DT</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="5%">TS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($employee as $row){?>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="id[<?= $row['id_p']?>]" value="<?= $row['id_p']?>"></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="dt[<?= $row['id_p']?>]" value="1" disabled></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="ts[<?= $row['id_p']?>]" value="1" disabled></td>
    </tr>   
    <?php } ?>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('[name="id[<?= $row['id_p']?>]"]').click(function() {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if (checked) {
            $('[name="dt[<?= $row['id_p']?>]"]').prop('disabled', false);
            $('[name="ts[<?= $row['id_p']?>]"]').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('[name="dt[<?= $row['id_p']?>]"]').prop('disabled', true);
            $('[name="ts[<?= $row['id_p']?>]"]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });

})
```

Comment: Please click `<>` and post HTML and JS instead of PHP in a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating the logic by attempting to use the row identifier in the selector. You can instead generalise the logic to avoid the need to use that by using DOM traversal.

Put a common class on the `id[X]` checkboxes, then use `closest()` to get the parent `tr`, then `find()` the relevant checkboxes within that. Then you can enable/disable them based on the state of the `checked` property. Also note that you should use the `change` event on checkboxes, not `click`, for accessibility reasons. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggle').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('disabled', !this.checked);
  }).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl_employee" class="table table-striped table-bordered show-child-rows" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center" width="5%">ID</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="5%">DT</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="5%">TS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="id[0]" class="toggle" value="0"></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="dt[0]" value="1" disabled></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="ts[0]" value="1" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="id[1]" class="toggle" value="1"></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="dt[1]" value="1" disabled></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="ts[1]" value="1" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="id[2]" class="toggle" value="2"></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="dt[2]" value="1" disabled></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="ts[2]" value="1" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would trigger the change onload too - as in my answer

Comment: Thanks it's solved and simple..bit weak me in jquery logic

Answer (score 1):

You need to not use the disabled html attribute but trigger the change onload to set the initial state.

Note I find the other checkboxes in the same row instead of addressing them directly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name^=id]').on("change",function() {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $(this).closest("tr").find('[name^=dt]').prop('disabled', !checked);
    $(this).closest("tr").find('[name^=ts]').prop('disabled', !checked);
  }).trigger("change"); // trigger onload
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl_employee" class="table table-striped table-bordered show-child-rows" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center" width="5%">ID</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="5%">DT</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="5%">TS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="id[1]" value="1>"></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="dt[1]" value="1"></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="ts[1]" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="id[2]" value="2>"></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="dt[2]" value="2"></td>
      <td class="text-center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="ts[2]" value="2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks @mplungjan for helping me first answer above has overcome my problem, and your answer also true.